# E/(18707): java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to get image from `URL` to `ImageView` I'm curently using [this](http://theandroidcoder.com/utilities/android-image-download-and-caching/) class. I have added permission to connect to internet write_SD card and so on, to `AndroidManifest` the problem is that it returns error `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to add image to `ImageView` using this function:`

```
public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    try
    {    
        if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) 
        {
             //TODO:Caching code right here
             String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
             File f = new File(getCacheDirectory(hm), filename);

              // Is the bitmap in our cache?
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());

              //No? download it
              if(bitmap == null){
                  BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                  DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                  imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                  task.execute(url);
              }else{
                  //Yes? set the image
                  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              }
         }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("",e.toString());
    }
}`
```

The question is what could be wrong and how could i fix this?
i will be pleased if you could point me in the right direction.

Logcat:

```
`06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at com.jandans.geos.ImageDownloader.download(ImageDownloader.java:51)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at com.jandans.geos.vaikpied$1.onItemClick(vaikpied.java:98)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-06 09:38:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(18832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

Comment: What's your need? You want to display some image from `URL` and should display in `ImageView` right?

Comment: Line 51 is ' imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);'

Comment: My need is to add image(witch is got from URL like in example http://hvz.eu5.org/upload/1.jpg) to imageview in my costom dialog.

Comment: it implies that `downloadedDrawable` is `null` due to some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one -

```
public class ImgLoadFrmWebActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imv1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Drawable image = ImageOperations(getApplicationContext(),"http://hvz.eu5.org/upload/1.jpg","image");
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
    private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Make sure the permission is added in your manifest file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Simply customize this layout with your needs. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @J1and1 Your required image is showing perfectly by use of my code. Check it out.

Comment: I found my mistake in My 'arrayadapter' forgot to add 'myview' in front of 'findviewbyId(R.id.image);' thats why there was an error :)